# Exporting data to txt file

Tags: export

I am doing a calculation that I have set the precision to 20 i.e. `N[expression,20]` and the output on Mma is indeed 20 significant digits, but when I export this number to a txt file, I get more than that. Any idea how to remedy that, and my txt file to contain the same 20 digits that they are output to Mma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try blocking [`$NumberMarks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$NumberMarks):

```
Block[{$NumberMarks=False},
    ExportString[N[{Pi, E, Pi^E}, 20], "Text"]
]
```

> ```
> "3.14159265358979323846
> 2.71828182845904523536
> 22.4591577183610454734"
> ```

or:

```
Block[{$NumberMarks = False},
    Export["file.txt", N[{Pi, E, Pi^E}, 20], "Text"]
];
Import["file.txt", "String"]
```

> ```
> "3.14159265358979323846
> 2.71828182845904523536
> 22.4591577183610454734"
> ```

Comment: Thank you. But would you have an explanation on why this happens?

Comment: Hi again. I tried what you proposed but it still doesn't work. The Mma GUI gives 20 digits significant precision, i.e. `-6548.825915592645347` but the exported txt file gives `-6548.82591559264534722455056080277298421799\`19.81219934315515`.

Comment: @hal What export format did you use, what was the exact Export call you used? And, what was the Mathematica version and OS?

Comment: Hi again, ok it worked. I didn't include the `"Text"` piece in the export. But any idea why without it, it fails to impose the `$NumberMarks = False`?