# On numbers with N digits after comma in Mathematica

Tags: output, number-representation, table

Consider a table

```
tabb={{1.233546576,2.454546565},{22334.46687875465,6787233.3565665655}}
```

I want to convert it into a table where all the numbers are only with 4 digits after the comma, and then export it (to save size of the output file).

This is what I do:

```
tabbSh={NumberForm[#[[1]], 4],NumberForm[#[[2]], 4]}&/@tabb
```

However, the elements of the resulting table become non-numeric. Could you please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: When you say `4 digits`, do you want a rounding or truncation? e.g., `Round[tabb, 0.0001]`

Comment: If you just want to truncate digits, you can try something like: `foo[x_, n_] := N[FromDigits[RealDigits[x, 10, n]], n]`

Comment: Similar questions: [143294](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143294/10397) (unanswered) [970](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/970/10397), [241413](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241413/10397), [19387](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19387/10397). In which format do you want to `Export`?

Comment: Thank you guys!